# Flex AreaChart CSS: Can style area fills but not area strokes and alpha?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm working on this AreaChart. But how come I can set area fills through CSS but not area strokes and alpha? That makes no sense!

```
<fx:Style>
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

  mx|AreaChart { chartSeriesStyles: Series1, Series2; }
  .Series1 { areaFill: #999999; areaStroke: #666666; alpha: 0.8; }
  .Series2 { areaFill: #cccccc; areaStroke: #999999; alpha: 0.8; }
</fx:Style>
```

It only works when I take out the areaStrokes and alphas.

I got the alphas working by doing:

```
<mx:AreaSeries ... alpha="0.8" />
```

But the same does not work for areaStrokes:

```
<mx:AreaSeries ... areaStrokes="#999999" />
```

What should I do?

Mats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AreaStrokes and fills aren't just simple colors, but objects: SolidColor and Stroke.  You'll have to check this to see how to set them:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_02.html

You'll probably have to set them in the MXML.

```
<mx:AreaChart ...>
   <mx:areaStroke>
      <mx:Stroke color="0xff0000" weight="2"/>
   </mx:areaStroke>
   <mx:areaFill>
      <mx:SolidColor color="0xffff00" alpha="0.8"/>
   </mx:areaFill>
</mx:AreaChart>
```

Comment: You have to admit though - it makes little sense that one can't simply do this in the CSS, right?

Comment: I don't see an obvious logical reason why you can't use CSS to set this.  The technical limitations are simply SolidColor is only a plain old object unconnected to the view hierarchy.